# Unable to solve thisReverse for 'read_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['read_post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, html, django

I have a navbar in my template in which I am trying to add an active class, however, whenever I do such, I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'read_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['read_post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'read_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['read_post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\Abdullah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Abdullah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Abdullah\\Desktop\\Blog\\my_blog',
 'C:\\Users\\Abdullah\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Abdullah\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Abdullah\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Abdullah\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Abdullah\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Abdullah\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 21 Apr 2021 09:38:37 +0000
```

here is my base.html:

```
`{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/posts.css' %}">
{% url 'posts' as posts %}
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="nav_a {% if request.path == posts %} active {% endif %}" href="{% url 'posts' %}">Blogs</a></li>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a class="nav_a" href="{% url 'myposts' %}">Welcome {{ request.user }}</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_a" href="{% url 'post' %}">Post</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_a" href="{% url 'myposts' %}">My Posts</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_a" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a class="nav_a" href="{% url 'signup' %}">Signup</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_a" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>
<br>

<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body
</html>`
```

here is my urls.py:

`"""my_blog URL Configuration

```
The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from blog_app import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.posts, name='posts'),
    path('signup', views.signup, name="signup"),
    path('login', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='blog_app/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='blog_app/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('post', views.post, name='post'),
    path('myposts', views.myposts, name='myposts'),
    path('delete_post/<int:id>', views.delete_post, name='delete_post'),
    path('edit_post/<int:id>', views.edit_post, name='edit_post'),
    path('read_post/<int:id>', views.read_post, name='read_post')
]`
```

posts views.py:

```
`def posts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog_app/posts.html', {'posts': posts})
`
```

here is my blog_app/posts.html:

```
`{% extends 'blog_app/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}    
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div>
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        
        <a href="{% url 'read_post' post.id %}"><button>Read blog</button></a>

        
        <h4>Posted by {{ post.author }} on {{ post.datetime }}</h4>
        
        <br>
    </div>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}`
```

models.py:

```
`from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_time = timezone.now()
    # datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto=timezone.now)`
```

Also pls suggest way to add active link class as I am unable to do that.

Comment: Show the contents of `blog_app/posts.html`. Also remove all othe views code than the view `posts`.

Comment: just did that, plz have a look at it

Comment: Have you set some primary key on the `Post` model yourself? Try writing `{% url 'read_post' post.pk %}` instead of `{% url 'read_post' post.id %}` (`post.pk` instead of `post.id`). If that doesn't work show your `Post` model.

Comment: I didn't set primary key as I thought there was no need of it. Also I don't think there is a need a need of passing id into {% url 'posts' post.pk %}.

Comment: I didn't say anything about `{% url 'posts' post.pk %}` though? I am talking about the line `{% url 'read_post' post.id %}` in `blog_app/posts.html`.